# Multiline Highchart based on Dates

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to create a multiline highchart which takes 24hrs in x axis and for each date plot one line.

```
[{
        "date": "2017-05-01T02:50:26",
        "value": 764.88
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-05-02T12:29:07",
        "value": 978.66
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-05-04T08:30:20",
        "value": 522.61
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-05-04T12:29:34",
        "value": 762.7
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-05-02T11:09:56",
        "value": 809.96
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-05-03T03:32:35",
        "value": 736.94
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-05-04T12:56:53",
        "value": 339.68
    }
]
```

Here we have 4 unique dates i.e

> 2017-05-01 , 2017-05-02 , 2017-05-03 , 2017-05-04

and we want four lines of each date. But the x axis has to be hour:minute and y axis is value. I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbxteehf/2).

Answer (score 0):

To change the way xAxis labels display, you can use `Highcharts.dateFormat()` function inside `xAxis.labels.formatter`. Take a look at the example posted below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Highcharts.dateFormat

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/x41vev1p/

Comment: But in this case all four line have different x axis range. But i want one range in x axis which all the lines use it. I want to have 00:00 - 24:00 in x axis but not separate for each line.

Comment: You need to set the same timestamps for all series or set each series to different xAxis. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bf8vLLbb/.